# Running Kubernetes Locally via minikube

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kvm, minikube

I am working on openam deployment on Google cloud platform (GCP) and the OS is RHEL7.
I am facing issue while running minikube start.

```
[root@test ~]# minikube start 

Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 150.53 MB / 150.53 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
E0509 06:20:12.950109   16264 start.go:159] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory.

 Retrying.
E0509 06:20:12.951500   16264 start.go:165] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
```

I already installed virtualbox on RHEL. 
I want to know how to enable VT-X on GCP?

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: So you're trying to run VMs within a Google Cloud Platform VM? Can you not run the contained VMs directly on the platform? I am surprised VT-X isn't enabled already but I expect it's that way for a reason: I'd be very surprised if you can get Google to enable it on a host for you.

Comment: You can run Minikube on your own machine. It wont work on a cloud VM due to VT-X disabled.

Answer (score 4):

[You can use](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) `--vm-driver=none` to run your minikube in cloud. This flag will run your minukube in Docker. You should have installed Docker first.

Also you can create a custom image where VMX will be enabled. Just follow the [official documentation instruction.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) 
Example from the documentation on how to create a custom image with enabled VMX:

```
gcloud compute images create nested-vm-image --source-disk disk1 --source-disk-zone us-central1-a  --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"
```

Then, just create a new VM with the custom image.

```
 gcloud compute instances create example-nested-vm --zone us-central1-b   --image nested-vm-image
```

After all, you can install the VirtualBox or KVM and start minikube.

Comment: I found additional information and update the answer